# Adding files or directories to play distribution

Tags: playframework

How can one add files or directories to the packaged distribution created with *play dist*? For example directory *data* and all of its contained files?

Thanks in advance!
M.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on what kind of files do you mean. I.e. storing for an example some JSON with data for some front-end script best location is just `public` folder, so you can access it easily with `routes.Assets.at` helper.

On the other hand, config files and other resources that shouldn't be available for the client should be stored under the `conf` folder.

Comment: Neither the one nor the other. I have a directory _data_ (and others) that contain various files which need to be contained in the distribution, but I cannot find documentation about that.

Comment: So put them to `conf`

Comment: Putting non-config files to directory _conf_ just to get them packaged, seems not to be the right way, I think. Isn't there an other possibility to get them packaged?

Comment: That's the Play convention, you can just create a subfolder in `conf` for your resources, optionally you can as well create own folder and add it manually to classpath, all belongs to you.

Comment: OK, I think I've got the point now - from the perspective of the Play! Framework application specific data is considered as _config_ data. Thank you for your help.